# python - generate random number

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function that generates a random number between 0 and 100 using random,
I wrote this code but I only get numbers betweem 0 and 1
what can I do to fix this

```
import random
def randint (min= 0, max = 100):
    num = random.random()
    return num
randint()
```

Comment: [`random.randint(0, 100)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) or [`random.randrange(0, 101)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange)

Comment: Multiply it by 100.

Comment: And then use `floor()` to convert it to an integer.

Comment: Are you trying to reimplement `random.randint()`? If not, just use it.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. This is worth looking at [the documentation for the random module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html). In there, you can see that `random.random()` is designed to "Return the next random floating point number in the range \[0.0, 1.0\)", and there's a whole [subsection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-integers) of functions for integers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try passing the min & value to the randint()

```
import random
def randint(min=0,max=100):
    a = random.randint(min,max)
    return a

randint()
```

Comment: Most likely it's an academic exercise to learn how to write this algorithm.

Comment: oh, that makes sense. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This may help you using random inside function:

```
import random 
def RANDOM(i):
    for i in range(100):
        n = []
        n.append(random.randrange(0, 100, 1)) 
        return n

for i in range(100):
    Text = RANDOM(i)
    print(Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use randrange() or randint(), for this,  taken from this guide:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

```
import random as rn

def randint():
    num = rn.randint(0,100)
    return num
```

try that. Hope it works